# Every service method in transaction

Tags: transactions, persistence, transactional

We have layered application, Controllers, Services, Repositories. Controllers for request mapping, Repositories for data access and Services for business logic.

Services can call Repositories or other Services methods. Is it ok to execute all methods in Services in transactions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can execute all methods in Services in transactions.

@Transactional, meaning that any failure causes the entire operation to roll back to its previous state, and to re-throw the original exception.

Comment: Yes, we can, but is it ok to execute all methods in Services in transactions? How much will decrease performance?